# How do I fix audio issue on Samsung S21FE? I can't hear voice directions after checking all phone and app v olume settings

Tags: audio, maps

The Google maps application functions but without any audio. I have rebooted the phone and checked that all volume settings are on full volume, and  I have made sure the google maps application volume setting is not on mute